# input type validation javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How i can validate file type??. The following error throw an exception "theFileElement is not found"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Data", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload"/>

}


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e){

            filename = theFileElement.value;
              if (!/\.csv$/i.test(filename)) {
                alert("Please upload csv file only");
                return false;
              }
              return true;

        });

</script>
```

Comment: It's not found because you don't have any element called 'theFileElement'. if you're referring to the file dialog, give it an id, and use $('#FileUpload') to reference it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theFileElement is not defined anywhere.
add

```
var theFileElement = document.getElementById("FileUpload");
```

before

```
filename = theFileElement.value;
```

Also edit your file input to look like

```
<input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload" />
```